# Highlight search results in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am usiong laravel 5.5, I have a blade template in which I have a search, I want when the user types a keyword so the results comes with highlighted keywords. I have a code which works fine but when i try to loop it, shows me an error:

**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

my controller:

```
    $keyword = $request->name;

    $searchres = DB::table('brands')       
        ->select('*')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")->get();

    $search = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i", "<b>$1</b>", $searchres);

    return view('frontend.ft_list', compact('search'));
```

blade template:

```
        @foreach($search as $result)
            <div class="card" style="border-radius: 1rem;width: 100%">
                <h5 class="card-header" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold">{{$result->name}}</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{$result->published}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">{{$result->user_id}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        @endforeach
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: whats your  output ===> `var_dump($search);`

Comment: OUTPUT:

:string '[{"id":1,"name":"<b>mc</b>donalds","logo":"brand\/V6gEShdmMeikOTCQNzVGHJkjFs2eyT0TRDI1KUkV.jpeg","published":1,"self_managed":1,"user_id":8,"created_at":"2018-05-31 11:25:38","updated_at":"2018-06-05 14:14:13"}]' (length=211)

Comment: i don't see any description and  location attribute . that's why error occurs .

Comment: I have edited my question, I had to change my query while posting the question here, currently is too long and messy anyhow the main issue the foreachloop it doesnt display the data in loop when i use preg_replace in controller

Answer (score 2):

Ok i have an idea and i hope that it going to help you

```
$keyword = $request->name;

$searchres = DB::table('brands')       
    ->select('*')
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($row) use ($keyword) {
        $row->name = preg_replace('/(' . $keyword . ')/i', "<b>$1</b>", $row->name);
        return $row;
    });

return view('frontend.ft_list', compact('searchres'));
```

and in the blade use

```
{!! $yourvariable !!}
```

and don't use

```
{{ $yourvariable }}
```